# mySQL 5.1 to 5.5 upgrade - radio button data error

Tags: custom-fields, mysql

We have upgraded MySQL from 5.1 to 5.5 and now when we extract the data what was previously showing as yes/no is now showing as 1/null, in addition the first row of data is showing the correct yes/no values.

[image]

This seems only to be affecting custom fields which used the inbuilt yes/no radio field type.

Where we had custom alphanumeric fields, type radio, yes/no value options - the data is fine. So a fix could be to reset up all the fields affected as alphanumeric, re-import the data and then delete the old fields  -  but this will no resolve the underlying issue. Concerned if we do this it might come back to bite us later.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I did made a test against Civicrm 4.6.10 against Mysql version 5.6.30

where I did created two custom field with option as below

1. custom alphanumeric fields, type radio, yes/no value options
2. custom Integer fields, type radio, 1/2 value options

Both gets saved against database as excepted first one with alphanumeric got saved as yes/no and other one got saved as 1/2

So I would recommend you to create a new custom field with alphanumeric and try importing the records again which should import correctly.

I guess this helps!!!